# Pull text via Textract from S3 Object via Lambda in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-textract

I know that's a mouthful of a title, but I've been hit a wall and thought I'd reach out to see if there was something I'm missing.

**my goal:** a lambda that will access a file inside an S3 bucket, run it through textract and then write the results to an RDS database. (at this point to get access to RDS i have to run my lambdas in VPC)

So, I have my lambda function that is running inside a VPC. I have setup the necessary permissions,policies,endpoints, etc such that the lambda can access s3 documents using the following code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'my-bucket'
    key = my-file.json'
    try:
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        json_data = data['Body'].read()
        return json_data    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Now... here is the problem. I replace the above code with the following code and run inside the VPC - i get the dreaded timeout.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Document
    s3BucketName = "my-bucket"
    documentName = "test.png" 
    # Amazon Textract client
    textract = boto3.client('textract')

    # Call Amazon Textract
    response = textract.detect_document_text(
    Document={
            'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': s3BucketName,
            'Name': documentName
    }    })
   # Print detected text
    for item in response["Blocks"]:
    if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
        print (  item["Text"] )
```

When the lambda is run outside of a VPC, i.e "No VPC" selected under the Network heading in the lambda, this second chunk of code runs without issue.

Does anyone know what might be causing this to fail? I haven't found anything in the docs that say that this case is prevented, but I'm worried that I may not be able to access Textract from inside a VPC?

Comment: Amazon Textract is currently available in the US East (Northern Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), US West (N. California), EU (Ireland), EU (London), and Asia Pacific (Sydney) . is your VPC in one of these regions?

Comment: i'm using us-west

Comment: @cotfessi Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ambigus9: I broke the process up.  like the comment below regarding moving the results of json into an s3 bucket and then set up a second lambda to react to an s3 put.  hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it isn't getting past the textract response?

If so just to double check ensure that the execution role has the AmazonTextractFullAccess attached to it.

Also its worth trying to pull the file from s3 first and attempt to run textract on the local file, to check whether its an issue between textract and s3 specifically.

**Then there is this old reliable fix:**

Extract the text in a non-vpc lambda and dump results in json to S3, then have that trigger another lambda IN a VPC which can access your RDS DB.

Comment: i'm leaning toward the "old reliable fix"... just seems like textract can't interact with S3 through a VPC

Comment: @cotfessi Any solution about it? I can't make textract interact with S3 through a VPC either

Answer (score 0):

Textract is available within your VPC if your VPC exist in one of the following regions (as of Jan. 2020):

- US East (Northern Virginia)
- US East (Ohio)
- US West (Oregon)
- US West (N. California)
- EU (Ireland)
- EU (London)
- Asia Pacific (Sydney)

If your Lambda function that is invoking the Textract API is timing out, it may be due to the fact that the Textract API call time is longer than the Lambda function timeout. In this scenario, you can use the asynchronous Textract API `StartDocumentTextDetection` - where your Lambda function can just kick-start the background process and you can get notified via SNS when the job has completed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_StartDocumentTextDetection.html

Comment: I'm using us-west... and initially i was worried when i started seeing the timeout error that i wasn't giving it enough time, but when it completes successfully outside a VPC it takes between 4-5 seconds. inside vpc i have the timeout set to 1min and it still runs out. Could it take that much more time through the vpc?